# How to check if a web server is installed in a Linux machine?

Tags: linux, webserver

Good morning folks,

Basic question :-)

1. How to check if a web server is installed in a Linux machine?
   I dont know if any web server installed or not. If installed I would like to use it to build a web 
   service.
2. If a web Server installed, how to check where it is installed, path , properties etc..

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 39):

If there's a webserver *active* it's easy enough to tell, but if the webserver is installed, but not active, it's more difficult, since there are probably a dozen different webservers that *might* be installed (but haven't been started). You can tell if there's a web server *active* on the default port for http (80) with:

```
$ telnet hostname 80
```

Where `hostname` is the hostname or IP address of the machine of interest. If you have shell access to the machine of interest, then you can just use `localhost`, for example, if there is a webserver active, you will see something like:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

If you type something like:

```
GET /foo
```

You will get an error message that may tell you something about what webserver is installed. For example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>404 Not Found</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Not Found</h1>
<p>The requested URL /status was not found on this server.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.2.22 (Ubuntu) Server at 127.0.1.1 Port 80</address>
</body></html>
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

This would tell you that *Apache* version 2.2.22 is installed and running on the machine that you're running the shell on.

If there is no webserver active, on the other hand, you will see something like:

```
$ telnet localhost 80
Trying 127.0.0.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
```

In this case, things get rather more distribution-specific (what you find and where is dependent on the Linux distribution installed). You can try to see if there's a webserver *installed*, but not active, by checking for common service names or installed files and directories. You could try:

```
$ service apache2 status
```

or

```
$ service httpd status
```

And you might get:

```
Apache2 is NOT running.
```

This at least tells you that *Apache* is installed, but not running, whereas:

```
apache2: unrecognized service
```

... would tell you that *Apache* is *not* installed. There could, however, be another webserver installed.

You might also check to see if there's a `/var/www/` directory, or another directory where webservers commonly store files by default, e.g.:

```
$ ls /var/www
```

Unfortunately, it's hard to give a good answer without knowing what distribution (e.g. Debian, Ubuntu, RedHat, CentOS, Fedora, ...) is installed on the machine of interest.

Comment: Thank you to you both - the asker and the answerer. Of multiple problems I am facing, your answer solved the first one.

Answer (score 2):

Take Apache HTTP Server as example, there is a directive call ServerSignature

Check with HTTP Response header
There may be something like

```
Server: Apache/2.2.17 (Win32) PHP/5.2.17
```

Of course the server can turn this feature off

You may try firefox addons "Web Developer" to get those HTTP headers

The best way to check the operating system is to find the server host, getting the user account and do a login :-)

For your second question, please login it and search for appropriated tutorial of that OS